# How to find the latlng of a circle's edge?

Tags: android, google-maps, edge-detection

I want to find the circle edge(endpoint) `latlng`. - in Android's google-map API.
(all `latlngs`. because I want to know that users escape circle or not...)

Is it possible?

[image]

This is my storyboard. I mean, I want to know the black points' `Lat.Lng` value. The radius is 100m.

Comment: can u explain why you added that extra characters in question

Comment: Please Check this answer by Daniel Nugent [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30431417/10020648).

Comment: Use [J.Doe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10020648/j-doe) suggestion, or just calculate distance of your point to center of circle and compare it to radius of circle.

Comment: You can use geofences as well: https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing